# Go client example to fetch storage account keys

Tags: azure, go, azure-blob-storage

How can we get the Azure storage account key from storage account name and other parameters ?

I tried to build the storage account client but it requires, storage account name and key to build the client. I want to fetch programatically storage account key using storage account name and other parameters. Equivalent Go Sample code to below Azure CLI command.

```
az storage account keys list --resource-group --account-name
```

Can you please give some pointer, how can i fetch using Go sample code ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To get keys for a storage account, you will need to make use of [`Azure SDK for Go`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go) especially [`armstorage`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/sdk/storage/armstorage)`.

Here's the code sample for listing account keys:

```
func ExampleStorageAccountsClient_ListKeys() {
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to obtain a credential: %v", err)
    }
    client := armstorage.NewStorageAccountsClient(arm.NewDefaultConnection(cred, nil), "<subscription ID>")
    resp, err := client.ListKeys(context.Background(), "<resource group name>", "<storage account name>", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to delete account: %v", err)
    }
    for _, k := range resp.StorageAccountListKeysResult.Keys {
        log.Printf("account key: %v", *k.KeyName)
    }
}
```

This sample and more code examples are available here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/main/sdk/storage/armstorage/example_storageaccounts_test.go.

Comment: This is useful in case you already have login with "az login" on terminal then this default credentials works. How can we generate the credentials using client ID, client secret & tenant ID and storage client based on that creds.
I tried below code and even though it is valid secret, it shows wrong secret. How can we generate client using those creds?

`cred, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential(tenantID, clientID, clientSecret, nil)`

it says error `Invalid client secret is provided.` in `ListKeys` API.

Comment: The code should work. Have you checked if the secret has not expired?

Comment: Yes, it is not expired for sure.